# if statement checking for characters in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
  int hours, xhours, deduct, NP, tax_check; //variables store numbers
  char F_N, G_N, del, uwc; //Variables to store letters
  float rate, tax, GP; //Variables to store decimals

  printf("\nWould like to deduct $20 from your weekly pay as a contribution for to the United Way Charity: "); //Ask user for a donation
  scanf(" %c", &uwc);

  if(uwc == 'y'){         //Donation reduction outcome     !!!Need help for this code!!!
    uwc = 20;
    deduct = tax + uwc;
  }
  else{
    deduct = tax;
  }
  printf("\n&d", deduct); //Testing the outcome

  return 0;
}
```

My question is that when I ask the user if they would like to donate and they say yes, I want my if statement to be activated by looking at the stored "yes". How can you do that? Also when ask the user for a donation, it only stores the first letter, why?

Comment: ok i will go do that

Comment: The code you've posted is full of noise, including several lines that have been commented out. You need to [edit] to clean it up to a [mcve]; while you're making that [edit], you can also work on making it more clear what you're asking.

Comment: There, I fixed the code

Comment: `tax` is unitialised variable. `printf("\n&d", deduct);` is an error. Please enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `uwc` is a `char`, `"y"` is a string, which is `char*`. How do you expect that to match correctly?

Comment: I was just cleaning up the code. What I want is the if statement to check for uwc is = to y.

Comment: Barmar, even if I do 'y', it does work. It displays %d.

Comment: No, it displays `&d` which is what you told it to.

Comment: ohh, I just noticed that. Thanks, I'm gonna check that out.

Comment: Don't use uninitialized variables. They contain unknown trash.

Comment: This is only a shortened code. Those variables actually being used in the real code.

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Before posting a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (uwc == "y")
```

to

```
if (uwc == 'y')
```

Double quotes are for strings, single quotes are for characters, this is basic C syntax.

Comment: what difference would it make? Will %d store characters?

Comment: `%d` parses the input as a number, and stores the numeric value into the variable.

Comment: `%c` reads a single character, and stores that character into the variable.

Comment: You need to go back to your textbook or tutorial, and learn how this works. I'm not going to try to teach all about C data types and input parsing here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding you just want to check if what the user inputs is equal to "yes"? In that case `strcmp` is a standard function in the c library and can be used by including `string.h`. This function doesn't account for captialization though so if the user inputs "Yes" for example it won't work. Otherwise if you're just looking to compare a single char (the char "y" for example) that can be done in a direct if statement like this

```
if(input == 'y'){
    //do things
}
```

This will also not account for capitalization. Also note the use of single quote marks as that means you're comparing a char single quotation means char in c and double quotation means string.

P.S. if you need help with strcmp here's the man page https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp

Comment: @manavdubey err.. well if you look at other people's suggestions they do tell you what to do. First of all you need to change your input from `%c` as that's only used for chars and chars only store on character. Second you actually need to declare uwc as a char array if you want to store the entire input from the user. Here's an example: http://ideone.com/Yu4goU

Now obviously you would add your own error checks like i mentioned in my first comment but this is to answer the rest of your question about storing input.

Comment: its fine, I got the code down now. But thanks for helping anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to learn `string` in C then you will understand how to input a `string` and how to compare a `string` your `uwc`is a `char` mean character variable, a `char` variable only can  hold one character not a word or a `string`

Check out these tutorials,

[tutorial 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)

[tutorial 2](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings)